# Identifying the availability of contact details by parsing a page in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, module, nltk

Any python modules or code snippets to get the following requirement done will be helpful.

I want to read a page and identify whether there are any resume content or the contact details(name, email, mobile.no, address) in the page.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Could you give us some more information, like : what you tried, an example of what you want to get data from and what data you would get for this example. Thanks.

Comment: what's it with all the resume questions recently. it that a new coursera class or something?